# Qt C++ Как лучше взаимодействовать с UI разных классов

Tags: c++, qt, gui, виджет

Вот тестовый пример, создаю класс Form и работаю с его ui в mainwindow. Предполагаю, что это плохой способ, но доступный. Как всё же взаимодействовать с ui? Через get/set? через сигналы и слоты? покидайте подобных тестовых примеров, буду благодарен.

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
~Form();

//private:
Ui::Form *ui;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"


Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Form)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "form.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
Form *form;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

form = new Form();
form->ui->lineEdit->setText("Qt");

connect(this->ui->actionForm, SIGNAL(triggered()), form, SLOT(show()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Как правило, ненужно взаимодействовать с ui другого класса. Например, ваше окно Form, предназначено для какого-то действия (запросу у пользователя некой информации или уведомления пользователя о чем-то). Объявите в Form сигналы/слоты/свойства связанные с этими действиями, а не со структурой редактора.

Comment: Зависит от того, для чего нужен Form. Возможно, вам стоит почитать про модальные\немодальные окна и то, как их правильно вызывать. Например, здесь: http://itnotesblog.ru/note.php?id=230 . В любом случае, наверное, неправильно создавать объект Form в конструкторе, лучше делать это через слот по сигналу triggered(), как у вас.